# How to assign a list to a read-only/init-only property using initializer syntax without hard-coding it, e.g. in JsonPolymorphismOptions?

Tags: c#, properties, initialization, system.text.json

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class Base
{
}

public class Foo : Base
{
}

public class Bar : Base
{
}

public static void TestA()
{
    JsonPolymorphismOptions options = new JsonPolymorphismOptions
    {
        DerivedTypes =
        {
            new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Foo), nameof(Foo)),
            new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Bar), nameof(Bar)),
        }
    };
}
```

It compiles just fine.

However, the following code does not compile:

```
public static void TestB()
{
    IList<JsonDerivedType> subtypes = new List<JsonDerivedType>()
    {
        new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Foo), nameof(Foo)),
        new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Bar), nameof(Bar)),
    };


    JsonPolymorphismOptions options = new JsonPolymorphismOptions
    {
        DerivedTypes = subtypes
    };
}
```

I get a

> Error CS0200  Property or indexer 'JsonPolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Well, I can obviously assign it in the first initializer in `TestA`, why not in `TestB`? And is there a way to assign a previously assembled list to the `DerivedTypes` property in `TestB` without hard-coding it?

I assume the problem is not related to `System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPolymorphismOptions` but rather to my general usage of initializer syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Well, I can obviously assign it in the first initializer in TestA

No, you can't. That's not what the initializer does.

This code:

```cs
JsonPolymorphismOptions options = new JsonPolymorphismOptions
{
    DerivedTypes =
    {
        new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Foo), nameof(Foo)),
        new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Bar), nameof(Bar)),
    }
};
```

... is equivalent to:

```cs
JsonPolymorphismOptions options = new JsonPolymorphismOptions();
options.DerivedTypes.Add(new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Foo), nameof(Foo)));
options.DerivedTypes.Add(new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Bar), nameof(Bar)));
```

That's how [collection initializers](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/expressions.md#117154-collection-initializers) work.

To add the members of an existing list, you can use:

```cs
JsonPolymorphismOptions options = new JsonPolymorphismOptions();
foreach (var type in subtypes)
{
   options.DerivedTypes.Add(type);
}
```

You could potentially create an `AddRange` extension method on `IList<T>`, allowing you to write:

```cs
JsonPolymorphismOptions options = new JsonPolymorphismOptions();
options.DerivedTypes.AddRange(subtypes);
```

Note that in both cases, the original list ends up being independent from the list exposed by `options.DerivedTypes` - if you call `subtypes.Add(...)` afterwards, `options.DerivedTypes` will not be affected.

Comment: I was totally unaware of the inner working of collection initializers and their `Add()` call chain. That was very helpful. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TestA() is adding elements to DerivedTypes and TestB() is giving it a new object

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to assign a previously assembled list

```
    var subtypes = new[]
        {
        new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Foo), nameof(Foo)),
        new JsonDerivedType(typeof(Bar), nameof(Bar)),
    };

    TestB(subtypes);
```

method

```
public static void TestB(IEnumerable<JsonDerivedType> subtypes)
{
    JsonPolymorphismOptions options = new JsonPolymorphismOptions();

    foreach (var subtype in subtypes)
        options.DerivedTypes.Add(subtype);
}
```